# How to turn off superfluous headers in Django?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django application running with a WSGI server. Things are working fine, but my responses are coming back with lots of headers like -

```
{
  'Date': 'Fri, 20 Sep 2019 15:11:34 GMT',
  'Server': 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'TERM_PROGRAM': 'iTerm.app',
  'PYENV_ROOT': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv',
  'TERM': 'xterm-256color',
  'SHELL': '/bin/zsh',
  'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/r1/v5jp8l016j9b3nb97tk224qs07cp6s/T/',
  'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jAa5tsZccM/Render',
  'TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION': '3.3.0',
  'TERM_SESSION_ID': 'w0t2p0:EB83BE59-190F-4819-BE37-618016E6C685',
  'PYENV_VERSION': 'hodor_env',
  'ZSH': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.oh-my-zsh',
  'USER': 'siddharth.saha',
  'COMMAND_MODE': 'unix2003',
  'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FB43X5s2aG/Listeners',
  'PYENV_DIR': '/Users/siddharth.saha/src/hodor/hodor_app',
  '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x407658D9:0x0:0x0',
  'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/hodor_env',
  'PAGER': 'less',
  'PYENV_VIRTUAL_ENV': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/hodor_env',
  'LSCOLORS': 'Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad',
  'PATH': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv/versions/hodor_env/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/libexec:/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/siddharth.saha/src/go_parsers/vendor/bin',
  'PWD': '/Users/siddharth.saha/src/hodor/hodor_app',
  'ITERM_PROFILE': 'Default',
  'PYENV_HOOK_PATH': '/Users/siddharth.saha/.pyenv/pyenv.d:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.13/pyenv.d:/usr/local/etc/pyenv.d:/etc/pyenv.d:/usr/lib/pyenv/hooks',
  '_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1': '${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)',
  'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0',
  'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0',
  'PYENV_SHELL': 'zsh',
  'SHLVL': '1',
  'HOME': '/Users/siddharth.saha',
  'COLORFGBG': '7;0',
  'GOROOT': '/usr/local/go',
  'LC_TERMINAL_VERSION': '3.3.0',
  'ITERM_SESSION_ID': 'w0t2p0:EB83BE59-190F-4819-BE37-618016E6C685',
  'HODOR_BUILD_ENV': 'dev',
  'LESS': '-R',
  'LOGNAME': 'siddharth.saha',
  'LC_CTYPE': 'UTF-8',
  'GOPATH': '/Users/siddharth.saha/src/go_parsers/vendor:/Users/siddharth.saha',
  'LC_TERMINAL': 'iTerm2',
  'PYENV_ACTIVATE_SHELL': '1',
  'SECURITYSESSIONID': '186a9',
  'COLORTERM': 'truecolor',
  'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'api.settings',
  'TZ': 'UTC',
  'RUN_MAIN': 'true',
  'SERVER_NAME': '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
  'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
  'REMOTE_HOST': '',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
  'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'WSGIServer/0.2',
  'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
  'PATH_INFO': '/ping',
  'QUERY_STRING': '',
  'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
  'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
  'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8000',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'python-requests/2.18.1',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
  'wsgi.input': '<_io.BufferedReader name=4>',
  'wsgi.errors': "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>",
  'wsgi.version': '(1, 0)',
  'wsgi.run_once': 'False',
  'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
  'wsgi.multithread': 'True',
  'wsgi.multiprocess': 'False',
  'wsgi.file_wrapper': "<class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>",
  'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'Content-Length': '36'
}
```

As you can see lots of these headers are basically superfluous and I have no need for them. When I run my app in production, `nginx` complains that my header size is too big.

Is there a way to just include the necessary headers?

Edit: My Django settings are -

```
"""
Django settings for api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xu)g8c(45zc36!_52_*231l39z)97dlsbfmbd%wiyrt69g*c3z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    # See: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
    'rest_framework',
]

LOCAL_APPS = ['api']

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {

}

# Logging
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'full_logging_formatter': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(process)d|%(thread)d ' '%(name)s.%(funcName)s():%(lineno)d %(message)s'  # NOQA
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default_handler': {
            # File based
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'full_logging_formatter',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/logs/hodor.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'api': {
            'handlers': ['default_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

HOST = "hodor.goibibo.com"


# NewRelic configuration filepath
NEWRELIC_CONFIG_PATH = '/etc/newrelic/newrelic_hodor.ini'
```

Comment: Usually you deploy your WSGI server behind a reverse proxy, e.g. Nginx. You can configure your server to clear headers e.g. use [`more_clear_headers`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_headers) in Nginx.

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? looks like you're running it in debug mode.

Comment: I am running the `django.core.wsgi` server. Yes, I was running with `DEBUG = True`. I changed it to `DEBUG = False` and it's no longer running in debug mode, but I still get all of those headers back.

Comment: where do you actually see this list? in your browser dev tools?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use django.core.wsgi in production. It cannot handle multiple parallel requests. Use gunicorn or uwsgi behind nginx. But I don't really understand why your WSGI returns the environment variables as part of the headers, that's why I'm asking where do you see this? How do you produce this output?

Comment: I get it with cURL - `curl -i -X GET -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://localhost:8000/ping`

This returns all the headers in the question. Thanks for the tip on not using `django.core.wsgi`

Comment: You must have some setting somewhere that adds all environment variables to the headers, this is typical some debug setting. Are you using django-debug-toolbar or django-extensions?

Comment: I don't think so. I edited the question with my settings as well.